# Very high cardinality and time series data, what DB to use?

Tags: ruby, time-series

I have a system that adds about 250,000 records every day, and then allows users to perform real time Analytics on them. The systems performs fine with the exception of one field--phrases.  This field is the interesting phrases we extracted from the document. It has massive cardinality, basically by definition. And because of this, performance grinds to a halt when I try to generate a top 10 list.

So I am looking for alternatives.

Has anyone used s graphite for something like this? RRDtool? Other solutions?

Comment: Doesn't both graphite and rrd store time-series type data? What you describe does not seem like such a problem. What about converting phrases (if they are long) to something like md5 hashes and using MemCached to update their frequency in real-time. I.e. just throw memory at the problem and update the top 10 list in real-time. That way you don't get one massive daily calculation, but instead split the task into many tiny calculations as the records are added.

Comment: Yes, I was on my iPad when I typed it. So, it corrected it for me.

Comment: So, the thing is that I have something like 120 million "points" of data in time, with like 1 point. So, that's why I wonder if they wouldn't work so well.

Comment: So, the issue, is that these change over time. Part of the "solution" is to understand the mix and how it changes over time. What comes into the top 10, and what leaves, is important.  I agree though that this could be best way to do this.  But, if I can have my cake and eat it too.. that would be better.

Comment: This should probably be asked on http://dba.stackexchange.com instead of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I've seen this done in a time series database, where people track phrases in tweets over time.  Each phrase is a series, and you can easily track how popular a phrase is over time (aka trending topics).  This seems different, but related to the summarized top ten you are looking for, however.

Comment: yeah, that approach is what i'm leaning toward.